# Ayuda con mi OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbuilder

Estoy teniendo problemas al querer hacer consultas de un servidor a otro, uso power builder con una conexión .ini en la cual esta como principal el MSS Microsoft SQL Server, no hay problema hasta ahí. Lo malo es cuando creo un proc y hago una consulta en mi primer if es local(Lima) pero en mi segundo if(Pisco) que es otro servidor al cual quiero jalar datos, no lo hace y me sale error.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  

SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
    'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVIDOR;UID=SA;PWD=PASSWORD',
    'SELECT COD_USER, DESC_USER, USER_ABV
    FROM SIGCONSULTAS.dbo.SVUSERS
    ORDER BY COD_USER ASC') AS a;
```

Cuando genero esa consulta en el sql server, no me sale error pero cuando lo hago en el power builder ANSI_NULLS y ANSI_WARNINGS en las propiedades lo pongo como true y se quita el problema pero deja de funcionar otro procedimiento almacenado. Habrá una opción de OPENROWSET que se conecte con mi .ini como MSS Microsoft SQL Server??...

El mensaje de error:

> Ha ocurrido un error de la base de datos. Código de error en la base
>   de datos: 7405 Mensaje de error de la base de datos: Select error: Las
>   consultas heterogéneas requieren que se establezcan las opciones
>   ANSI_NULLS y ANSI_WARNINGS de la conexión. Así se asegura una
>   semántica de consulta coherente. Habilite estas opciones y vuelva a
>   emitir la consulta.

Comment: Sería bueno que agregaras a tu pregunta el mensaje completo del error.

Comment: Ha ocurrido un error de la base de datos.
Código de error en la base de datos: 7405
Mensaje de error de la base de datos:
Select error: Las consultas heterogéneas requieren que se
establezcan las opciones ANSI_NULLS y ANSI_WARNINGS de la
conexión. Así se asegura una semántica de consulta
coherente. Habilite estas opciones y vuelva a emitir la consulta.

Comment: Seria mejor que linkearas los servidores y usaras OPENQUERY, solo es una segerencia.

Answer (score 0):

En un entorno de consulta a servidores heterogéneos, como normalmente se considera a una consulta a través de `OPENROWSET`, es necesario establecer dos valores importantes a nivel de conexión:

- [`ANSI_WARNINGS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), el cual establece si se debe generar un `Warning` cuando existan valores `NULL` en una función de agregación, por ej: `SUM()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, etc.
- [`ANSI_NULLS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), que establece como se realizan las comparaciones con un valor `NULL`

Lo que te dice el mensaje de error, es que debes "encender" estas opciones a nivel conexión, por ejemplo:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
    'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVIDOR;UID=SA;PWD=PASSWORD',
    'SELECT COD_USER, DESC_USER, USER_ABV
    FROM SIGCONSULTAS.dbo.SVUSERS
    ORDER BY COD_USER ASC') AS a;
```

Comment: Si probé con eso pero no funciono o bueno funciono pero cuando otra área estaba registrando le salía un error null cuando lo tenía encendido y cuando lo desactivo pueden registrar normal. En mi .ini cuando inicio la conexión lo tengo como "MSS Microsoft Sql Server" y no como "ODBD", podrá ser por eso?